# Can I make a completely empty LongArray in Kotlin instead of one filled with 0 (zeros)?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I'm starting to learn programming through Kotlin, mostly doing tasks (katas) through codewars. I'm stuck at one task (https://www.codewars.com/kata/steps-in-primes/) where it requires me to, if there are no prime numbers in given interval with defined step, return an empty long array.

I defined array as:

```
var result = LongArray(2)
```

I read somewhere (perhaps even on this site) that empty arrays are declared like that, but those 2 slots are instead filled with zeros. How can I "erase" those zeros to get a completely empty array?

Comment: besides `LongArray(0)`, there is also `emptyArray<T>()` available....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty array is one without any elements.

So to create one of size 0, you have to use `LongArray(0)`.

You cannot remove elements from an array. If you want to do that, you need to use a `List`.